# Why doing the prebuild in expo I get "Metro skipped: Project metro.config.js does not match prebuild template"

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Tis is my first app in Expo (React Native) so I have no idea why this is happening. This is the output after "npx expo prebuild":

```
✔ Cleared android, ios code
✔ Created native projects | gitignore skipped
› Metro skipped: Project metro.config.js does not match prebuild template.
› Ensure the project uses @expo/metro-config.
  Learn more
✔ Updated package.json and added index.js entry point for iOS and Android
› Installing using npm
» android: userInterfaceStyle: Install expo-system-ui in your project to enable this feature.
✔ Config synced
✔ Installed pods and initialized Xcode workspace.
```

this is my metro.config.file:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
    },
  };
})();
```

this is the metro config I always had during development so if you can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by adding:

> assetPlugins: ["expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles"]

Like this:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

   module.exports = (async () => {
        const {
           resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
        } = await getDefaultConfig();

return {
    transformer: {
        babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
        assetPlugins: ["expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles"],
    },
    resolver: {
        assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
        sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
    },
};
})();
```

Comment: can you explain why you had to do this?

Answer (score -1):

"Ensure the project uses @expo/metro-config."

So, replace `const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");` with `const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config')`

Comment: Note, this answer is wrong. You should import expo/metro-config as stated in the following docs: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/

Comment: i still get the warning when importing from expo/metro-config

Answer (score -3):

change `const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");`

to `const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');`

From double to single quotes